# Check if DWH tables existing in a dynamic way

Tags: sql-server, methods, dynamic, datatable, exist-db

In a SQL Server data warehouse, I have approximately 90 tables. During a nightly run, it can happen that a table is not created. I want to write SQL code that checks if every table exists, if possible in a dynamic way.

What would be the best way to do this? I assume that there are a lot of existing code samples to do this?

I am thinking about following steps:

In first step I have to create a fix table with all the table names right? I suppose if I use DWH_NAME.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES and select all relevant tables it can happen that the failed table is not included in DWH_NAME.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES?

In the second step, I need code that checks if the table names from the created fix table are included in DWH_NAME.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES.

Something like:

```
IF (EXISTS (SELECT *
            FROM DWH_NAME.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
            WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
              AND TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
              AND TABLE_NAME = 'TABLE_NAME'))
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Database table exists'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'No table in database'
END
```

In the third step, I have to create this code dynamically. TABLE_NAME should go through the 90 table names. An output that lists the 90 tables with the info if they exist or not would be nice.

Can someone confirm these steps or are there better methods? Maybe someone knows an appropriate dynamic code that was already written?

Many thanks.

I go through this article

[If table exists with dynamic query in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25179426/if-table-exists-with-dynamic-query-in-sql-server)

but was confused what `@TABLENAME` is and where it comes from.

Comment: Don't use `information_schema` in SQL Server use the proper `sys` DMVs - but as noted in your linked question, you don't need to. Presumably you have a list of tables that are required to exist?

Comment: Yes you need a list of tables you expect to be there, once you have the list from there you can simply use [`OBJECT_ID()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/object-id-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to check if the table exists (if it returns a value or not). e,g, https://dbfiddle.uk/dRJNknp9  No need for dynamic code, or loops etc

Comment: As an aside, having tables (presumably) dropped and created during nightly runs seems like an unusual process (to me at least). Perhaps the actual issues lie elsewhere and the check you are trying to perform is just papering over the cracks of something else that would be more worthy of attention.

Comment: Can you just left join your list of tables you expect to exist against `sys.tables` and find the rows that don't exist? something like `select * from @TablesIExpectToExist a left join sys.tables b on schema_id(a.SchemaName) = b.schema_id and a.TableName = b.name where b.name is null` ? Or if you want a flag saying whether the table exists or not, omit the `b.name is null` and add a field that says `TableExists = iif(b.name is null, 0, 1)`